# Android admob showing adview missing required XML attribute 'adSize'

Tags: android

I am using below code to implement admob in my application

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.google.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.admobdemo"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="a24dbba084368tf" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

but when i run the application i am getting an error message
adview missing required XML attribute 'adSize'
I am not able to get what is the actual problem in this code.

Here is my manifest file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.admobdemo"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=".Provider.Permission.WRITE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=".Provider.Permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably a namespace issue. You have to define the namespace.

try adding

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

Comment: hi Chirag thank for your reply i have done the changes but i m getting another error that is "you must have adactivity declared in manifext.xml"

Comment: Declare <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/> in manifest file.

Comment: Hi Chirag i m getting another error message that you can't add string types keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|s‌​creenSize|smallestScreenSize" in adactivity.

Comment: Yes my problem is solved. I din't change my code it was adUnitId
problem.
Thanks,